# SMTP and Direct Mail

Tags: smtp, typo3

I'm trying to sent Direct Mail Newsletters over SMTP but I didn't get it.
did you get to send Direct Mail Newsletter with SMTP?
Regards

Comment: What is your question?  What exactly have you tried, and where exactly is it going wrong.  Do you have any code to post?  Any error messages you can post?

Comment: @user1227684 Did You read extension manual ?

Comment: Which TYPO3 and direct_mail version?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with the current public version because direct_mail does not yet have adopted to the new mail API.